# How to make certain html page accessible only via confirmation link?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, email, cookies

My website contains a simple form asking only for an email. When the user submits the form, they're emailed a confirmation email asking to click "confirm subscription".

This is done using MailChimp. Once they click "confirm" they are redirected to my thank you page. This page however has a normal URL so its accessible just by typing it in your browser. Instead I'd like this thank you page to only be accessible if it's being opened via the MailChimp confirmation button within their email client.

Perhaps there's a way using cookies to verify the user is being redirected via MailChimp somehow?

Can you offer some advice how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a .htaccess page.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^[URL]/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /403.html [L,R]
```

This is what I use on my site to block people from accessing my assets folder. You just have to set the URL to whatever base URL that MailChimp uses.

Comment: That seems promising thank you! But I have a few questions. 1)  Would I simply replace /403.html with  MailChimp's base URL?  2)  Is this effective from mobile devices too? I need it to be reliable for that, and without cookies enabled, etc.  3) How do I determine MailChimp's base URL?  Isn't it just mailchimp.com? Thanks!!

Comment: 1) You could do that - or you could redirect to another page in on your webserver. 2) If you have a sample email from mailchimp which contains the confirmation button, I would use the base URL there. This is only because sometimes sites use subdomains for certain functions. This is for all traffic on your site, so yeah it works on mobile.

Comment: If I replace /403.html with my custom thank you page, then where do I input MailChimp's base URL?  Does it replace HTTP_REFERER like this: RewriteCond %{www.mailchimpsBaseURL} !^[URL]/.*$ [NC]

Comment: No, no. 403 is an error (it means that you're forbidden from accessing this page - here, I've made a custom page). The URL you want there is wherever you want to send someone who used the URL without first clicking on the confirm button. You don't replace HTTP_REFERRER, you replace the section [URL] to the mailchimp base URL. What this does is: Is the site that directed you to this URL mailchimp? If so, proceed, otherwise, go to some other page.

Comment: Ah! I understand, thank you. I just subscribed to my site and MailChimp sent an email from mail2.mcsignup.com . Is that the base email?

Comment: It should be, yes.                                                                          `Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mail2.mcsignup.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /redirectpage.whatever [L,R]`                                   Make sure that you use https if the site is in https! Also, make sure to format it correctly, I can't figure out newlines here.

Comment: Thank you, but that it's blocking my entire site. I need it to block www.mysite.com/page1.html  only. I also just clicked "confirm" within MailChimp and it blocked me out. Ok, I'll await your update. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that this file applies to the entire directory. You could make a separate folder for your file, and move the htaccess to it.

Comment: Ok now my site functions normally, but I'm getting blocked out when I click the "confirm subscription" button within my email. It redirects me to my error page, which is http://mysite/home/users/web/b1094/ipg.mysite/www.google.com .  Where google.com is my error page.  Getting 404 error - page not found

Comment: Can you please post the .htaccess file? I'd move this to chat, but I don't have high enough rep yet.

Comment: Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http: //mail2.mcsignup.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /google.com [L,R]

Comment: Try http ://mail2.mcsignup.com Get rid of the extra space, it was just so that the http show up. Also, .com/.*$

Comment: Try adding '/' after .com

Comment: I had originally, it's just that stackoverflow removed them in my comment. My htaccess file includes  !^ http ://mail2.mcsignup. com /.*$   no spaces

Comment: No change. That line shouldn't be the issue anyways, should it? It's function is  to block WRONG access (meaning not via MailChimp).. but my problem involves blocking the RIGHT access, meaning via the confirm button.

Comment: Dumb question, but you do have mod_rewrite enabled??

Comment: Dumber question, how do I tell? ;)

Comment: Make a php page `<?php phpinfo() ?>` Run it, check the section loaded module

Comment: I couldn't find mod_rewrite  anywhere on the file

Comment: I don't believe you have it. Are you on a VPS?

Comment: No, and I couldn't find mod_rewrite anywhere on that page either. I don't want to waste your time man, I can mess around with it if you want to take off. Really appreciate your help this far!

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified to assist you further. You could try contacting your hosting provider, but since I can't tell exactly what's going on, I don't think I can help you further. Thanks for following me through here. Have a good day.

Comment: Will do, you too. +1 since I feel I'm on the right track.

Comment: I feel this is the wrong approach to the question at hand. Would downvote if I had sufficient rep.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, cookies would be one method of approach for this. Within the redirected page, you can process a flag to mark the user as "Verified" and then use this cookie conditionally to display the additional data. This would be achieved by utitlizing one of the $_GET variables, and processing something from the form. You could always do this via a hidden form field. With mailchimp, I know they typically have a method of posting back processed form data as well. You could also use the $_SESSION super global. Yet another method would be to store a flag in the users database entry, if they are logged in, but obviously that would only work under those conditions.

Do keep in mind, using sessions or cookies for this is somewhat volatile, because if users for some reason have cookies disabled, it won't work.  Additionally, if they visit the site from a different device, this obviously wouldn't persist either. That's why you might want to enforce the database method through a user login, that way it's more reliable.

Yes, I was talking about on your site itself. An alternative to an entire user login system, would be  to grab their IP, store it in a DB table when they verify, and then check against when deciding whether to show the additional content. This in itself however might lead to a performance hit, especially as your user base grows.

However you could use that, in conjuction with cookies or a $_SESSION to essentially emulate them being logged in so to speak. Then once you have their $_SESSION set, you can check that on consecutive loads, instead of hitting the database. That's basically how traditional login systems are handled anyways, we're just doing away with the login requirement itself and using their IP instead.

Comment: Thanks Hybrid. I'd definitely prefer to use a reliable method, but I'm confused as to how I'd store a flag in the users database entry. Are you talking about doing something within MailChimp?  Or are you suggesting I add a member feature to my site. That seems like a large task for such a simple requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar set up for a lead generation page. The HTML form POSTS (using jQuery ajax) the page to MailChimp, which sends the users a verification link in an email. On my lead generation page I have a "hidden" div showing a thank you message. On successful post via ajax I just hide the div containing registration form and show the div with success message.

Since the div with success message is by default hidden, it will not show up unless the user submits the registration form.

I will not recommend using cookies in this scenario. What if the user opens the confirmation link on another browser or computer?

Comment: Thanks Tej, can you share your solution somehow or offer some example? Also, I don't know if your solution would work for me since it sounds like your Success Message appears before they've clicked "confirm" within their email? That means that in my situation, they could input keywords (on that success page) and submit before they had even confirmed their sign-up. I may be mistaken

Comment: You are right in your assumption. In your case you can 1) Configure a success message in MailChimp itself. 2) Configure in MailChimp to redirect to a success page and pass on a GUID in query string parameter. If the GUID param is not available in the URL or doesn't match, redirect the user back to registration page.